# How to plot the function definition domain

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot in a figure the domain my function is defined like the following [image]

Is there a nice way to do it within R?

**UPDATE:** I do not want to plot the function I want to plot the **domain description** (as a `legend` or `text`) like the image below [image]

Comment: Can you explain some more? Your example is defined for all real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example using `text` and some `plotmath` magic:

```
curve(ifelse(x==0,0,1/x))
text(0.8,60,expression(f(x)~"="~bgroup("{",
                        atop(1/x~~~x!=0, ~~0~~~~~x==0), "")
                        ),cex=2,col='red'
     )
```

[image]

**PS** I did some edits to get better result keeping always the first idea.

Comment: you almost divided by 0 there ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
plot(0)
legend("topleft", bty = "n",
  legend =  ~ f(x) == bgroup("{", atop(1/x ~~ x != 0, 0 ~~~~~ x == 0), ""))
```

[image]

*Revised* to put it within the area of the plot.